# JSP giving NullPointerException for request.getParameter()

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp

I'm new to jsp and am creating a webpage that has a form with a select box and a few other input boxes.
I'm populating these input boxes automatically with values from properties file:

NumConfig.properties

```
SELECT= , , 
ONE=1,I,FIRST
TWO=2,II,SECOND
THREE=3,III,THIRD
```

Here is my form:

```html
<html>

<body>
  <form name="NumDetail" id="NumDetail" method="post">
    <div>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th rowspan="2">Select
            <select id="SelectText" name="SelectText" onchange="this.form.submit()">
              <option value="ONE">ONE</option>
              <option value="TWO">TWO</option>
              <option value="THREE">THREE</option>
            </select>
          </th>
          <th align="center">Number</th>
          <th align="center">Roman</th>
          <th align="center">Position</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="center">
            <input type="text" size=10 id="number">
          </td>
          <td align="center">
            <input type="text" id="roman">
          </td>
          <td align="center">
            <input type="text" id="position">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

And this is the JS code I'm using to load values from properties file:

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  <%
  ResourceBundle resource = ResourceBundle.getBundle("NumConfig");
String dbname;
if (request.getParameter("SelectText") == null)
  dbname = "SELECT";
dbname = request.getParameter("SelectText");
String[] num = resource.getString(dbname).split(","); %>
var number = "<%= num[0]%>";
var rom = "<%= num[1]%>";
var pos = "<%= num[2]%>";

document.getElementById("number").value = number;
document.getElementById("roman").value = rom;
document.getElementById("position").value = pos; < /script>
```

I can indirectly open this page by appending ?SelectText value in the URL.
But when opening this page directly I get NullPointerException at the line

```
String[] num = resource.getString(dbname).split(",");
```

Two Questions:

1. How do I perform a null check or give the request parameter a default value so that page does not error out?
2. Once I select a value from the dropdown and the form submits, the select box does not retain its value and goes back to the default. How to resolve this?

Comment: Scriptlets are evil.

Answer (score 1):

You just need an `else` statement

```
if (request.getParameter("SelectText") == null)
    dbname = "SELECT";
else
    dbname = request.getParameter("SelectText");
```

---

To make an `option` selected by default, you should try this `selected="selected"`. Stock the value somewhere and change your selected option dynamically.

```
<option value="ONE" selected="selected">ONE</option>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly my recommendation would be not to mix Java code within HTML code in a JSP page. Try using a Java Servlet to manage your request and respose so you don't end up having a messy code.

I'll answer your questions below:

1. You are checking whether the parameter "SelectText" is null, and if that's the case then giving to 'dbname' a default value but the next instruction is replacing this given value with null.

The code should look like this:

```
String dbname = "SELECT";
String requestValue = request.getParameter("SelectText");

if (requestValue != null) {
    dbname = requestValue;
}
```

2. Have you tried replacing your form request method with GET instead of POST?

Comment: Thanks!!...How silly of me!
Tried changing the form to GET. It gives the same result.